# Gatsby - making a dynamic query to Contentful

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm working on a simple e-commerce based on `Gatsby` and `Contentful`.
One of my pages is `CartPage`.
So I'm trying to make a query to `Contenful` to get the necessary info about my products, so I want to pass a list of product ids that are in the user's cart.

Here's my component and query:

```
export interface CartPageProps {
  data: {
    products: GQL.ContentfulProductConnection;
  };
}

const CartPage = ({ data }: CartPageProps) => {

  const mockCart = [1, 2];
  console.log(data);

   return (
    <IndexLayout>
      <Page>
      //
      // Layout goes here
      //
      </Page>
    </IndexLayout>
    )
}
export default CartPage;

const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ProductsInCart($mockCart: [Int], $lang: String) {
    products: allContentfulProduct(filter: { idProduct: { in: [1, 2] }, node_locale: { eq: "en" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          idProduct
          price
          title
          quantity
          photo {
            resize(height: 200, width: 200) {
              src
            }
          }
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Now all I get on a `console.log(data)` is `undefined`.

If I do the same query but with `useStaticQuery` with all the data hardcoded - I get the desired data. But `useStaticQuery` doesn't accept variables.

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I pass variables to the query and put my data to the props?

Comment: It looks like you might have forgotten to export the graphql query?

Comment: @DerekNguyen you're right, but I think that's not the case. I think the problem is that `Gatsby uses GraphQL at build-time and not for live sites.` as said [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-concepts/#how-do-graphql-and-gatsby-work-together)
So it's not intended for making GraphQL queries on the go, as `fetch()` for example.

Comment: @SergeiKlinov Yes, you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby uses GraphQL at build-time and not for live sites. as said [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-concepts/#how-do-graphql-and-gatsby-work-together) So it's not intended for making GraphQL queries on the go.